# Customize switch symbol in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

How to globally customize these switches (create a \newcommand or custom environment)

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[spdt, xscale=-1] (Sw) {} (Sw.in) node[right] {in} (Sw.out 1) node[left] {out 1} (Sw.out 2) node[left] {out 2};
    \end{circuitikz} %yscale = -1

    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[spdt] (Sw) {} (Sw.in) node[left] {in} (Sw.out 1) node[right] {out 1} (Sw.out 2) node[right] {out 2};
    \end{circuitikz}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

to have box around like this?

[image]

Edit: even reference to manual would be enough

Comment: If you really want a custom switch, a have tutorials at http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/multipole.pdf and http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/bipole.pdf

Comment: @John Kormylo these tutorials are faublous!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365065/new-switches-in-circuitikz-no-nc/365308?r=SearchResults&s=3|38.7065#365308 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347337/is-it-possible-to-change-the-arrow-head-of-the-switches-in-circuitikz/347506?r=SearchResults&s=4|23.9562#347506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem that you have copied the code without understanding the concept

```
    \draw (0,0) node[spdt, xscale=-1] (Sw) [red]{a}
```

(0,0) is the coordinate of the node, initially ypu have not given a name {}

I gave it a name {a} which is reversed bcause of the xscale=-1(same as mirror)

```
    \draw [red, thick] (Sw.in) -- (Sw.out 2);
```

simply draws a line from the node you have named (Sw.in) to (Sw.out 2)

[image]

What you want is **below**

[image]

The **MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[spdt, xscale=-1] (Sw) {} 
        (Sw.in) node[right] {in} 
        (Sw.out 1) node[left] {out 1} 
        (Sw.out 2) node[left] {out 2};
        \draw [red, thick] (-0.4,-0.4) rectangle (0.4,0.4);%<-----added rectangle
    \end{circuitikz} %yscale = -1

    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[spdt] (Sw) {} 
        (Sw.in) node[left] {in} 
        (Sw.out 1) node[right] {out 1} 
        (Sw.out 2) node[right] {out 2};
    \end{circuitikz}

    \end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Add in a

```
\newcommand environ
```

the **MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\boxspdt{%
    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[spdt, xscale=-1] (Sw) {} 
        (Sw.in) node[right] {in} 
        (Sw.out 1) node[left] {out 1} 
        (Sw.out 2) node[left] {out 2};
        \draw [red, thick] (-0.4,-0.4) rectangle (0.4,0.4);
    \end{circuitikz} %yscale = -1
   }

\boxspdt
\end{document}
```

Compiling

```
    \boxspdt
```

will give

[image]

**PS**
You should be able to  take the

```
\begin{circuitikz}...\end{circuitikz}
```

out of the definition above; then, your source would have

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\boxspdt
 :
 : 
<optional other components can be added here other code here>
 :
 :
 \end{circuitikz}
```

(You might also want to add a way to name your spdt('s) in that case. Perhaps an optional argument.)

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not the solution I need. Instead of drawing rectangle each time I draw switch I would like to define in preamble (or similar) my custom switch named 'boxed spdt' with box around to use it globally like \draw (0,0) node[boxed spdt, xscale=-1] (Sw) {} in document

Comment: so enclose the above definition in an environment \boxspdt

Comment: Would you be kind enough to complete it into your answear please?

Comment: please see the edit above

Answer (score 2):

One can use the other anchors of node `(Sw)` to draw a box around it, although it will pass through the `in` and `out` anchors.  Since the calc tikzlibrary is already loaded, it is relatively easy to add offsets.

Note that `[xscale=-1]` reverses `west` and `east` anchors.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[spdt, xscale=-1] (Sw1) {} (Sw1.in) node[right] {in} (Sw1.out 1) node[left] {out 1} (Sw1.out 2) node[left] {out 2};
        \draw[red] ($(Sw1.south east)+(4pt,-3pt)$)  rectangle ($(Sw1.north west)+(-4pt,3pt)$);
        \draw (3,0) node[spdt] (Sw2) {} (Sw2.in) node[left] {in} (Sw2.out 1) node[right] {out 1} (Sw2.out 2) node[right] {out 2};
        \draw[red] ($(Sw2.south west)+(4pt,-3pt)$)  rectangle ($(Sw2.north east)+(-4pt,3pt)$);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]