How to use the "flex" or "bend" option of curved arrow shape with circuittikz package?
I use the circuittikz package to typeset the figure as below with the MWE.

\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    \node at (.2,2.1) {$+$};
    \node at (.2,0.9) {$-$};
    \node at (4.2,1.9) {$+$};
    \node at (4.2,1.1) {$-$};
    \node at (2.8,.2) {$+$};
    \node at (1.2,.2) {$-$};
    \draw[thick,line cap=round] (0,0) to[V,l_=$\mathrm{U}$] (0,3) -- (1,3)
    to[spst=$\mathrm{S}$,invert,mirror] (2,3) 
    to[short,f_=$\mathrm{i_C}$] (4,3)
    to[C,l=$\mathrm{u_C}$,a=$\mathrm{C}$] (4,0)
    to[R=$\mathrm{R}$,a=$\mathrm{u_R}$] (0,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}

Unfortunately, I found that the curved arrow faced the problem introduced with the docs of tikz in section 16.3.8.

What's the best practice to fix the shape of the arrow in this case?

-------below is the figure I want to reproduce with circuitikz--------


Yep, this is a bad effect with the bending library and the "thick" option. If you remove thick,  the arrow is much better...

Arrowheads are added to the end of lines, so alignment with curved lines is always a bit off.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347337/is-it-possible-to-change-the-arrow-head-of-the-switches-in-circuitikz

Oh, thanks, I didn't found the relevant answer with proper searching-key, sorry!

Short, thick, curved lines with arrows stretch a lot the arrow-placing mechanism of TikZ. Moreover, the default arrow for switches is latexslim, which is an "old-style" arrow from early TikZ. You can have better options by setting the arrow used as one of the new ones (from the arrows.meta library), for example:
 \ctikzset{switch end arrow={Stealth[length=6pt, width=6pt, flex]}}

will give you

Or even
\ctikzset{switch end arrow={Triangle[length=4pt, width=5pt]}}


which is arguably more "on-style" with the current and voltage pseudo-arrows.
References in circuitikz manual  here, and in TikZ here
My suggestion, if you insist on thick lines for the wires, is to force the switch to the same thickness using its class:
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    \node at (.2,2.1) {$+$};
    \node at (.2,0.9) {$-$};
    \node at (4.2,1.9) {$+$};
    \node at (4.2,1.1) {$-$};
    \node at (2.8,.2) {$+$};
    \node at (1.2,.2) {$-$};
    \draw[thick, line cap=round] (0,0) to[V,l_=$\mathrm{U}$] (0,3) -- (1,3)
    to[spst=$\mathrm{S}$,invert,mirror,switches/thickness=1] (2,3) 
    to[short,f_=$\mathrm{i_C}$] (4,3)
    to[C,l=$\mathrm{u_C}$,a=$\mathrm{C}$] (4,0)
    to[R=$\mathrm{R}$,a=$\mathrm{u_R}$] (0,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


BTW, if you want the math font upright everywhere, you may think about changing the math font (maybe Euler?). And have you seen the "American" way of putting voltages in circuitikz, instead of manually positioning the + and - signs?
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{euler}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    \ctikzset{voltage=raised}
    \draw[thick, line cap=round] (0,0) to[european voltage source,v<=$U$] (0,3) -- (1,3)
    to[spst=$\mathrm{S}$,invert,mirror,switches/thickness=1] (2,3) 
    to[short,f_=$i_C$] (4,3)
    to[C,v^=$u_C$,a=$C$] (4,0)
    -- (3,0) to[R=$R$,v=$u_R$] (1,0) -- (0,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



Thanks for yr brilliant solution, as for yr question of manually placed the + and -, my origin target is just to reproduce the figure I appended at the last of original question, the location of + and - I found a little difficult to control to make them in the place, so I used that silly method to modify its location.... Is there some key provided by circuitikz to make the code more elegant?

One possibility is my second example. Otherwise, if you want to mimic more closely your example, you can use american voltages and tweak the position... Better scope for another question, I think.

@Explorer, I give more options (I had a bit more time to dig into it).
